# SSRS Parameter Start Date 1 year ago of current month thru 1st day of current month

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters

Is there an expression in SSRS where I can set the default parameters from 1 year ago on the first date thur the 1st day of the current month?

Example: Start Date 8/1/16 End Date 8/1/17

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SSRS Expressions are pretty powerful.  What have you tried?

Comment: Check out `DATEADD()` or `DATESERIAL()` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep a cheat-sheet of common date calculations around, and then in my reports I'll create a new data set like the one below, using it to set the initial parameter values:

```
SELECT StartDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()) AS DATE))
    , EndDate = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

[Here's an example set of date calculations](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/cheat-sheet-calculating-important-dates)

Comment: This works! Thanks for sharing. I'll bookmark the link.

Comment: NP! You can also do this sort of thing with SSRS functions, I just hate working in that syntax.